# How do I list pods sorted by label version in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I need to list some pods sorted by version and get the last index of it.

I'm trying to do like:

```
kubectl get pods 
--namespace my-namespace
--selector "app.kubernetes.io/name=my-cool-pod"
--sort-by='.items[*].metadata.labels["app.kubernetes.io/version"]'
--output jsonpath="{.items[-1:].metadata.name}
```

But it is not working.

Also, my pod labels are:

```
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-instance
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: my-manager
      app.kubernetes.io/name: my-name
      app.kubernetes.io/version: x.y.z
```

How to I list pods sorted my version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out

Lables in K8S are for filtering, and not sorting.

I've just added a version field outside labels and it worked.